# pcregrep excluding multiple lines regexp eats one more line than needed

Tags: grep, perl, pcregrep

I want to filter out all lines starting with `banana` and all lines starting with a space after banana lines. I am using `pcregrep`. Consider the following file `fruits.txt`:

```
apple
banana starts matching
 this line should match
 this too
 and this
mango
pomelo
```

`pcregrep` happily finds what I want:

```
ars@ars-thinkpad ~/tmp/tmp $ pcregrep -M  'banana.*\n(\s.*\n)*' fruits.txt 
banana starts matching
 this line should match
 this too
 and this
```

However, if I try to exclude these lines, `pcregrep` eats mango too, which is not good:

```
ars@ars-thinkpad ~/tmp/tmp $ pcregrep -M -v 'banana.*\n(\s.*\n)*' fruits.txt 
apple
pomelo
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `\s` in the regex means that the expression can eat newlines.  I'm not familiar enough with how the `-v` is implemented in pcregrep to know why it's not the inverse, but I'm pretty sure that's the cause.

If you change your file to be:

```
apple
banana starts matching
 this line should match
 this too
 and this

mango

pomelo
```

Then even without the `-v`, the matching looks like it's not what you intend.

```
$ pcregrep  -M 'banana.*\n(\s.*\n)*' fruits.txt
banana starts matching
 this line should match
 this too
 and this

mango

pomelo
```

If it's truly only a space at the beginning of the line that should match, I suggest changing the `\s` to one or more spaces `" +"`.

When I change the regex to `'banana.*\n( +.*\n)*'`  It matches (both regular and inverse) in a way that I think is more correct.  Maybe use `[ \t]+` if tabs are allowed as well.

Comment: You are right that I should use tabs or spaces instead of `\s`, but the general answer is not quite true: my `pcregrep` 8.39 still eats mango with `pcregrep -M -v 'banana.*\n( +.*\n)*'`. Yours doesn't?

Comment: @ars may be you got `\r\n` line endings instead of just `\n`... check it with `cat -A` or `file` commands

Comment: While late to the party, I like `[^\S\r\n]` for "any kind of whitespace that isn't `\r` or `\n`". I was able to formulate a regex with and without the **-v** flag: `pcregrep -Mv 'banana.*(?:\n[^\S\r\n]+.*)*'`

Answer (score 0):

Such tasks are better suited for `awk` imo

```
$ awk '!/^ /{f=0} /^banana/{f=1} f' fruits.txt 
banana starts matching
 this line should match
 this too
 and this
$ awk '!/^ /{f=0} /^banana/{f=1} !f' fruits.txt 
apple
mango
pomelo
```

- The order of setting flag helps to easily print or negate the specific lines being searched as `!/^ /` condition is satisfied for line starting with `banana` as well
- `!/^ /{f=0}` if line doesn't start with space, clear the flag
- `/^banana/{f=1}` set the flag if line starts with `banana`
- `f` prints the lines matching condition while `!f` negates the condition

Comment: "Better suited" is a very personal opinion, I think (-;   `pcregrep` is a specialized tool for such tasks, whereas `awk` is a general tool and needs a script that is longer and more complex than the expression needed for `pcregrep`.

Comment: yeah, hence the `imo`... but I disagree about this being `complex` especially when pcre features like lookarounds are not needed here.. and it is definitely much better suited when it comes to dealing with various related cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern

Comment: Surely not complex, but at least more complex than a simple regex (a state machine and three conditional branches are hidden in that script). And of course: When cases get more complicated, tools like `sed` or `awk` or at some point `python` are better suited. Not yet in this case, IMHO.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a simplified example and I do need lookaround feature of pcregrep. Thanks anyway.