# How does pcregrep works?

Tags: perl, pcregrep

I have a file:

```
This error
-this
-this
-that
[text I want]
This error
-asd
-asfag
-adsfhs
[text I want]
[text I want]
This error
-asdgsda
-asdgg
-gasdg
```

I want to match to match except `This error and next three lines`, I can use:

```
pcregrep -vM  'This error\n.*\n.*\n' file
```

It gives output:

```
[text I want]
[text I want]
[text I want]
```

However, instead of removing them if I want to match them using the same command(by removing `v`):

```
pcregrep -M  'This error\n.*\n.*\n' file
```

It gives output:

```
This error
-this
-this
This error
-asd
-asfag
This error
-asdgsda
-asdgg
```

So how does `pcregrep` actually works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pcregrep excluding multiple lines regexp eats one more line than needed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383023/pcregrep-excluding-multiple-lines-regexp-eats-one-more-line-than-needed)

Comment: @muru in that question replacing `\s` with 'space' solves the problem.

Comment: Actually [it didn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383023/pcregrep-excluding-multiple-lines-regexp-eats-one-more-line-than-needed#comment681032_383042): "the general answer is not quite true: my pcregrep 8.39 still eats mango with `pcregrep -M -v 'banana.*\n( +.*\n)*'`"

Comment: https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcregrep.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `.*` to the end of your regexp.

```bsh
pcregrep -M  'This error\n.*\n.*\n.*' file
pcregrep -vM 'This error\n.*\n.*\n.*' file
```

I don't know if it's due to a bug or not, but it seems `-v` also excludes the full line after the last matched `\n`, but without `-v` it doesn't. So adding `.*` (i.e. not ending the regexp with `\n`) makes it match the last line explicitly in both cases, therefore not triggering the issue/feature.

Comment: I know that adding `.*` will work, but I am looking for reason.

Comment: It's almost as the condition is: if `.*<pattern>.*` matches, skip the line(s) (which would make sense for a single-line invert)

Comment: @muru not looking for reason why this answer is working, looking for the reason why question which I asked is not working?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv that comment applies to both.